# Find related nodes with matching attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode

I have an xml document with the following structure:

```
<MyDocument>
  <MyObject>
    <MyKeyValue value="1"/>
    <MyKeyValue value="2"/>
  </MyObject>
  <MyObject>
    <MyKeyValue value="3"/>
  </MyObject>
  <MyMetadata>
    <MyMetadataObject value="1" dataIWant="abc"/>
    <MyMetadataObject value="2" dataIWant="def"/>
    <MyMetadataObject value="3" dataIWant="ghi"/>
  </MyMetadata>
</MyDocument>
```

In my code I am iterating through each MyObject node as follows:

```
foreach (XmlNode objectNode in document.SelectNodes("//MyObject"))
{   
    // I want each //MyMetadata/MyMetadataObject where the 
    // metadata @value attribute equals my objectNode's @value
    foreach (XmlNode metadataNode in documentNode.SelectNodes(/* WHAT XPATH */))
    {
        myListOfData.Add(metadataNode.Attributes["dataIWant"]);     
    }
}
```

I can see that to get to the `MyMetadata` node from `objectNode` I can use the following

```
objectNode.SelectNodes("../MyMetadata")
```

and to get the MyMetadataObjects I need the following:

```
objectNode.SelectNodes("../MyMetadata/MyMetadataObject")
```

However I need a filter on those nodes and that's where my problem is:

```
objectNode.SelectNodes("../MyMetadata/MyMetadataObject[./@value = /*objectNodes's @guid*/")
```

How can I find all `MyDocument/MyMetadata/MyMetadataObject` that have a `@value` attribute that matches a `@value` attribute in `MyDocument/MyKeyValue`

Answer (score 1):

"*...where the metadata `@value` attribute equals my `objectNode`'s @value*". It isn't clear to me because `objectNode` may have multiple values. Maybe something like this is acceptable (I assumed changing the outer loop to each `<MyKeyValue>` node is fine) :

```
foreach (XmlNode objectNode in document.SelectNodes("//MyObject/MyKeyValue"))
{
    var xpath = string.Format("../../MyMetadata/MyMetadataObject[@value='{0}']", 
                                objectNode.Attributes["value"].Value);
    foreach (XmlNode metadataNode in objectNode.SelectNodes(xpath))
    {
        myListOfData.Add(metadataNode.Attributes["dataIWant"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code was already deployed but the xpath `/* WHAT XPATH */`was configurable so I was attempting to find a solution that would just require a config change. The `MyMetadataObject\@dataIWant' attribute used to be in the `MyKeyValue` node but the new version of a third party library changed it's xml format. We have implemented something similar to your answer but made it more a bit flexible. The inner foreach calls a custom function passing in the node and an array of xpaths. The text result of the first xpath can replace a wildcard in the subsequent xpath and so on.